# Static function in Java web application

Tags: java

I have a static function in a Class which is called by a Servlet. Suppose, if 100 requests come at a time, will that function be available for all the requests?

Comment: Click the check mark for good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the requests get processed by the same VM, in the same process, but different threads. So yes, any static members are available to all requests.

Be aware though that if you change static data from those multiple threads, you would do good to synchronize on that data for thread safety. or use ThreadLocal objects, these will be distinct for every thread.